# Adding new rows to a DataGrid appears blank

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm trying to add new rows to a `DataGrid`, but when I'm adding them they appear blank.

```
string[] test = { "hi", "bye" };
this.MessageDataGrid.Items.Add(test);
```

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="MessageDataGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Naam" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bericht"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

[image: Blank row after adding an item to the DataGrid.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each item in your `DataGrid` is an *array of `string`* with two elements. Use a `Binding` with an indexer (square brackets `[` `]`) to refer to each element. See [Binding path syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0#binding-path-syntax) for more information.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MessageDataGrid">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Naam" Binding="{Binding [0]}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bericht" Binding="{Binding [1]}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```